# Should [interview-questions] be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The tag [interview-questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview-questions) seems to be useless - should it be burninated?

Comment: The strongest case for keeping this tag in terms of answers posted to this question is "I find it interesting to see what's going on in interviews".  Obviously, as I'm always wrong about tags, my answer has received 3 quick downvotes... but if we're keeping the tag, this question would be well-served with a strong case for keeping the tag around.  One that can warrant a positive score that can keep up with my answer's negative score.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's rather a meta tag (like [homework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework)) but I find it interesting to see what's going on interviews.

Furthermore it helps to distinguish homework questions from interview questions which are sometimes very similar to each other.

So, I would not delete it.

Comment: OK, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

[interview-questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview-questions) is a meaningless tag. Whether a question is an interview question or not is completely irrelevant: it doesn't change the nature of the question or the expertise required to answer the question. It isn't useful to categorize the question or to make it more visible to its intended audience. It is a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and **should be deleted**.

[interview-questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview-questions) might still pop up from migrations from Stack Overflow, where it is being phased out but still present on some old questions.

Answer (score -4):

I don't think [interview-questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview-questions) is a particularly useful tag.

We allow the [homework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) and [beginner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) tags to stay because supposedly, as answerers, we're supposed to treat these questions differently (whether or not that actually happens is another matter).

I could see the same case being made for [interview-questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview-questions), however, in what way should [interview-questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview-questions) questions be treated differently?

Well, ideally, if the questioneer specifies what particular problem the interviewer had with the code, we can put ourselves in the mindset of a hiring company, think about what we'd expect to see in a candidate, think about why we were asking this particular question, and then try to answer how we might respond to receiving this code in an interview.

But... is this happening?  Most of the [interview-questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview-questions) questions I see don't specify any specific problem the interviewer had with the code.  Those that do specify extraordinarily vague reasons (to the point where it's not helpful).  And even when the questioneer is asked directly in comments, they often say "they didn't tell me", or something of the like.

So, what good does the [interview-questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview-questions) tag do?  Best case scenario, someone preparing for a job interview could search through the tag in an effort to prepare for an interview.  That's the only benefit I can see to the tag.

It doesn't add any useful information to the question.

Moreover, one of the reasons that has been mentioned in the past that you must be the owner (and now we allow maintainers) of the code submitted for review is because we don't want to allow reviews posted to Code Review be the basis for hiring/firing decisions.

While some (most/all) may be using the [interview-questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview-questions) tag in good faith and truly trying to just gain a better understanding of what was wrong with their code so they can do better in the next interview, it's not inconceivable to imagine a user who sees this tag and decide to use it to post code submitted as part of an interview (to help an interviewer make a hiring decision) *or* for a user to attempt using a set of mostly positive reviews to their code as an effort to suggest to a company that their assessment of the user's interview code submission was wrong.

I don't know how likely those described scenarios are, but with these possibly scenarios combined with the previously mentioned problems with the tag, I think it's certainly worth considering eliminating the tag.

Comment: *It doesn't add any useful information to the question.* - I disagree with that statement (-1 applied - because that statement is the underpinning of the rest of the answer). The tag implies a bunch of things from [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] to a bunch of other things, like abaility to search for other answers, time pressures, specific types of code-answers, etc. The tag ***is*** useful to me (and 53 people follow it too), regardless of whether it is to you.